# Document Set NewDocSet.aspx HTML Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

If we have a document set content type containing a 'publishing HTML' column type, then when creating a new document set (NewDocSet.aspx) there is no ribbon loaded thus no richt text HTML editor box is shown for the 'publishing HTML' column.

Is it possible to load the ribbon and RTE functionality via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by just using a custom application page form and adding the RTE textbox as SharePoint control